# "table or view does not exist" through oracle on PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g, pdo, oracle-call-interface

I get the error "table or view does not exist" when i try to access any from a table.
I'm using PDO with the OCI driver through PHP.
I've been having a really tough time finding help with using oracle through PHP.

```
$dbh = new PDO("oci:dbname=listst", DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

When I try `select * from entriedLevels` I get nothing back (even though entriedLevels exists and the user has select access).

When I try `select OBJECT_NAME from user_objects where object_type = 'TABLE'` I get nothing back.

When I try `select TABLE_NAME from all_tables` I can finally see all of the tables.

I apologize for my crummy writing, it's the end of a long day on a Friday... sorta brain dead.

Comment: Is this table in the user's schema? If no, it won't be returned when selecting from `user_objects`

Comment: try using the full schema.tablename in your query.  Since you can get select Table_name from all tables you're connecting to the database.  My guess is that either the connect string isn't specifying the database or if it is something is getting lost along the way so the db connection doesn't know which schema to access.

Comment: You are correct, as is the one answer that was provided.
I'm sure anyone who saw this was thinking "Oh man, what a n00b". Well, I am brand new to oracle and worst i'm not new to SQL, so I *think* I'm doing things correctly, combined with the fact that the error message was a little cryptic.

I suppose the key is to notice "view does not exist" and realize view, means your current perspective, which may be relevant to the current user, then you could google perspective or view and oracle, and find schema, and then be happy you know what is going on.
Ramble, ramble...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two alternatives come to mind:

- Qualify the table name with the owner of the schema it's in:

> select * from OWNER.entriedLevels

- Create a public synonym for the table:

> CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM entriedLevels FOR OWNER.entriedLeveles;

Comment: Or even better by using a *private* synonym where the tablename points to schema.tablename, so tablenames with same name but from different schema's do not collide